# Need Help In Creating htaccess rule. Redirect mobile user to Desktop site using query string

Tags: .htaccess

My requirement is, 
If i am accessing website www.example.com through desktop shows me desktop page and whenever i open www.example.com through mobile is shows me mobile page.

i did this using below rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/styles
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://mob.example.com/$1  [L,P]
```

now i want if i am accessing www.example.com through mobile its opening mobile page and in that mobile page there is a links called view desktop site and i want whenever i click that link it will open desktop page for me in my mobile. 
The query_string is force=desktop.
I tried with below rules but it did'nt work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} force=desktop   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|Android) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=302]
```

Comment: What is mobile versions URL and what is desktop URL?

Comment: Both are same. i have put htaccess rule if user agent is mobile then it will open mobile page which is handled by proxy and at the end of the mobile page there is Desktop version tab. and i want if user click on that desktop version tab then it will open desktop version page with with query string for eg (www.example.com/?force=desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    # force desktop version for mobile agents
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|Android) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1?force=desktop [R=302,L,NE,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !force=desktop
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/styles
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://mob.example.com/$1  [L,P]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not here, its not readable. Post this code by editing your question.

Comment: I have proxy rule which is working for my mobile site, but i want whenever user access mobile site and trying to access desktop site using mobile for eg link (www.exaple.com/?force=desktop) goes to desktop site

Comment: Nope It did'nt work for me. it just open the same page.

Comment: What URL did you open? Did you open from Mobile or desktop?

Comment: suppose i am accessing www.example.com in mobile and it shows me mobile version and there is a tab in mobile site which is (view desktop version) and if i clicked on that tab it will show me desktop site with query string like force=desktop, but its still showing the same mobile site

Comment: Nope just the second one which i have posted on my question.

Comment: Cryptic comments like these will not help you solve your problem. Lot more details needed. A tab on page etc doesn't make any sense for a web server. You need to check Web server log to clearly see what exact request is coming and what is `HTTP_USER_AGENT`

Comment: i want if useragent is mobile and trying to access desktop version with query string then he should go to desktop version.

Comment: Hope you realize that you're not answering my specific questions. Pls read my previous comment carefully and provide specific answer to those questions.

Comment: Kindly check my question, if anything is missing kindly let me know.

Comment: No it doesn't have answer to questions I asked. I am pasting again: `You need to check Web server log to clearly see what exact request is coming and what is HTTP_USER_AGENT (both from mobile and desktop tabs)`